# Is there a way to disable the background on the DisplayActionSheet using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

### Issue:

I'm dealing with an issue on how to disable the background on a DisplayActionSheet or DisplayAlert in Xamarin Forms, so the only way the user can "get out" of the popup windows is via the options that the window has prompted.

---

Here is the screenshot of the problem: 
http://postimg.org/image/s16cp66wf/

Do you know if there's a simple way to do this? I've been looking but I couldn't found....

### I tried:

Using the methods that came with the control but nothing else came up. What I'm doing right now is to call it till I have an answer.

**Code:**
From my code behind I call the event

```
async void OnNextClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await userValidations.RMLocationServiceWindow();
}
```

And then I call the popup window

```
public async Task RMLocationServiceWindow ()
{
    string rta = null;
    while (rta == null)
    {
        rta = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet("Do you accept to use the service?", "Cancel", "Continue");
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any that keep the focus on the windows.

Comment: Please list what you have tried already

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-).  Can you post some screen prints, code and any background research you have already done? This will help people, help you.

Comment: For anyone who has to deal with this problem and based on Winston suggestion, I end up navigating to another page with a frame on it, so the user has no chance but to click on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this could not be done in displayactionsheet, for you to be able to achieve this, you must create a Modal Page with list where you could be able to disable back button until there is a selection on the list. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your problem. If your problem is about when user not click 'Cancel' or 'Continue' and he click empty space, you wont get value for rta. Think about if user click white space it mean is canceling. This way may help you.

```
while (rta == null)
{
   rta = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet("Do you accept to use the service?", "Cancel", "Continue");
   if (rta==null)
     rta=="Cancel";

}
```